# Printing JavaScript escaped string safely in php

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

I am using `encodeURIComponent()` (and `encodeURI()` for e-mails) to take inputs safely from the user, and am then sending the output to php via ajax. The php processes it and puts this escaped sting into a `$_SESSION[]` which I then to to `echo` later.  I was wondering if it was possible to print this to html normally, and then have html ignore anything inside it being code (e.g.  would be treated as text instead of a tag) or even combine these two steps. I think the format for JavaScript encoding is different than that of php, so this might be an issue, but if it is, what would be the best way to change these stings in php (I'm storing these escaped strings in MySQL)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Javascript? You can simply do this in PHP before it tries to execute. Can't you just do `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: That's what i ended up doing, i usually answer my own questions if someone dose'nt post within 2 hours...

Answer (score -1):

Theese are the functions I use when I handle strings from users in php.

save is for save to database,

edit is editing in input/textareas

show is to write it out showing the tags as text in html.

```
// SAVE DATA
function save($str)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
//############################################################################
// EDIT DATA
function edit($str)
{
    $patterns[0] = '/</';
    $patterns[1] = '/>/';
    $patterns[2] = '/"/';
    $patterns[3] = "/'/";
    $replacements[0] = '&#60;';
    $replacements[1] = '&#62;';
    $replacements[2] = '&#34;';
    $replacements[3] = '&#39;';
    $str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    return stripslashes(stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '
', $str)));
}
//############################################################################
// SHOW DATA
function show($str)
{
    $patterns[0] = '/</';
    $patterns[1] = '/>/';
    $patterns[2] = '/"/';
    $patterns[3] = "/'/";
    $replacements[0] = '&#60;';
    $replacements[1] = '&#62;';
    $replacements[2] = '&#34;';
    $replacements[3] = '&#39;';
    $str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    return stripslashes(stripslashes(str_replace('
', '<br />', $str)));
}
```

play around with it and see if it works for you :)

Comment: thanks for the response, but i just encoded the strings in php instead.